# Convergence of sum and multiplication

Tags: convergence-divergence

Iv'e got a question and I find it difficult to me.

Let $ a_n,b_n$ be sequences. Assume that $a_n+b_n$ converges.

Is $a_n\cdot{b_n}$ essentially converges?

Prove.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider $a_n = n$, $b_n = -n$.

Comment: I thought about it, but isn't $-n^2$ converges to $-\infty$?

Comment: Many people (including me) would say $a_n b_n$ diverges. If you want a different example let $a_n = n$ for $n$ even, $a_n = 0$ for $n$ odd, and $b_n = -a_n$.

Comment: Like you, I think that "converges to infinity" is like "diverges", but we learned different, so I have to use these definitions.

Your second example is great!


I wrote $a_n=\{ n \ when \ n=2m \\ 0 \ when \ n=2m-1 $ and $b_n=-a_n$, thus $a_n\cdot{b_n}$ has two partial limits ($0,-\infty$), so it diverges.

Again, thank you!